# permission denied while copying eventhough necessary permission exist

Tags: linux, file-permissions, cp, umask

I have a file(file) with permission 500. In Linux, I tried to copy (using cp) that file into a folder (a) whose permission is 600. Even though folder have write permission, I am getting " cannot stat `a/file': Permission denied error.

Could anyone explain why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Is it because directory does not have executable permission ?
Execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside.
Plse see http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened for further info